# Remove all contacts in phone that don't have a phone number

Tags: contacts

My mother just upgraded from a simple flip phone to a [android motorola atrix 2](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/MOTOROLA-ATRIX-2-US-EN).  It's her first smart phone and she is having a very hard time adjusting.  She added her email and Facebook accounts onto the phone, as soon as she did so, however, it added all the contact information from both into her phone contacts.  She already had the contacts imported in from her last phone and is now dealing with duplicate contacts (such as "Mike Smith and "Micheal Smith").  The worst problem is, she is having a hard time finding a contact that actually has a phone number.  She'll search for "Jane Doe" in the phone when trying to call her and only find her email there.

**My Questions:**

1. Why does the phone (app?) show contacts that don't contain a phone number?
2. How can I delete the duplicates (or merge them)?
3. What is the best way to make this work as smoothly as possible?

Comment: Is she linking the contacts to a Gmail account? The Gmail Contacts web app makes it really easy to deal with duplicates.

Comment: Also check out [SIM contacts manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=ice.andrea.contactmanager). I used this to remove the imported contacts from the SIM card that kept showing up in my Phone/Contacts app as duplicates along with Gmail contacts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most Phone/Contacts apps list all contacts, from all added accounts by default. There are several system and application options that could resolve this confusion:

1. From the Home screen, press the Menu key and go to Settings -> Accounts & Sync.
2. Under the `Manage account` section go through each account (by tapping on them,) and verify that the `Sync Contacts` option is only checked for accounts that you really want to have synchronized with the phone.
3. Open the Phone app and go to the "Contacts" tab. press the Menu button and tap the `Display options` button.
4. Check the box next to `Only contacts with phones` option to hide any contacts that don't have a phone number associated with them.
5. Under the `Choose contacts to display` section, expand any accounts that you've chosen to keep in sync in step 2, and select the groups you wish displayed in the Phone app by marking their check-box.

Keep in mind that some manufacturers have their own versions of Phone and Contacts apps, so the menu choices might be slightly different (or even missing altogether.)

Comment: I do remember the option to only display contacts with phone numbers on my previous phone, the HTC Rezound. However, that menu option is missing on the OnePlus X, though I don't know if it's the phone or the new version of the app.

Answer (score 2):

I second Chahk's answer. Also, if you sync your contacts with your Google account, you can easily manage them online, including merging duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For the original "Questions", I would have added...
4. How do I either HIDE or GET RID OF contacts without phone numbers in the phone app?

Regardless, since this thread was asked and answered, Android Phone app now has different settings. In order to HIDE contacts without phone numbers...
Go to the Phone app
Click on the menu
Select "Settings"
Go to "Other call settings"
Turn on "Hide contacts without numbers"
Voila

Comment: This option is not available on the Google Phone app, so this might be an added feature done by the manufacturer/ROM maker. It might help to also mention the device model, Android version, and if not troublesome, the app's package name.